# PDFs come out either all black or pixelated when printed (with picture)

Tags: email, pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat, efax

Hey Fellow IT Guys,
         I have a couple of users who receive PDFs via eFax or Email and on the computer they look ok, but when they print it looks like this or either all black page

[image: Black PDF]

They use Adobe Acrobat Pro 8.1 and Reader 11

I have tried re-installing everything Adobe related and it is still happening
anything will be helpful.
Thank you!!
:D

Edit 1: It seems to be only affecting these 2 people, word docs and other program print perfectly, but for only a select few PDFs that the user has attained via email or eFax (not every emailed PDF either).

Comment: In addition to Julian Knight's answer - you might want to check if it prints similarly on another program - I'd probably use word, convert the file to PDF and try again.

Comment: No, the problem does not occur on any other documents for those users. Only PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this issue and found an option on the print dialogue selected called "Print color as black".  After unticking this option it resolved the issue.  This was on Acrobat Pro X.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a different printer?

It looks to me as though the fuser unit is shot on your laser printer. If it is an inkjet, then I think that you will be needing a new one.

Comment: well its only affecting 2 people out of 150, and everyone on that side of the building shares the same printers but they can print word docs and other files but it only affects PDFs that have been emailed or sent via Efax